# Access certificate signature from a certificate

Tags: java, x509certificate, pki

I'm working on a project where i need the digital signature to proceed further.I tried all the built in methods,bt sadly,nothing worked!

This is what i want to extract:

Algorithm: [SHA512withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 60 3B FA 8C 49 CF 97 E3   8B 04 F6 FD 75 23 5D 96  `;..I.......u#].
0010: E0 17 C4 10 03 FC 90 B9   9B 4C 00 43 C0 5A F5 08  .........L.C.Z..
0020: 93 0A 38 FA 13 42 39 B7   CE 27 DE 47 01 FB 0F EB  ..8..B9..'.G....
0030: 28 FB 59 FA FD 04 70 A6   A5 E1 4D 59 5D 03 3C 2E  (.Y...p...MY].<.
0040: 5B 9B 03 3B 2A 16 2B 72   0D 58 20 93 8D C6 77 92  [..;*.+r.X ...w.
0050: D3 A9 D3 AA 0F 02 69 77   94 F4 FA 3F 02 21 34 53  ......iw...?.!4S
0060: 00 96 24 5C 67 5A 80 61   89 5D 0F AA 74 63 1A EF  ..$\gZ.a.]..tc..
0070: A1 98 EC 7C A8 52 D8 F5   42 10 18 4F 4D 66 98 FA  .....R..B..OMf..

Please help me out...

Comment: It might help to know what you need the signature for. For an X.509 signature the getSignature() method should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you say the built in methods don't work, but that's not very useful. How are they not working? And what does your code look like?

You should be able to load the certificate using a CertificateFactory, then cast it to an X.509 certificate. From there, the `getSignature()` method returns a byte array containing the signature and `getSigAlgName()` returns the algorithm used to compute the signature. All of this is pretty well documented in the Java API documents: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html

Comment: Can you explain how i can verify the certificate genuinity? something like getting the public key from the issuer and then decoding the client certificate!!.

Comment: Look at the Certificate class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html, there's a verify method in it.

Comment: where can i find the actual method definition of verify() method?

Comment: where can i find the actual method definition of verify() method? I need to know how the method actually works. !! Is verify() method sufficient enough to check whether the certificate is genuine? I need to check the certificate chain.

Comment: That is actually the point of verify, it follows the certification chain and verifies the signatures. If it says the certificate is valid, you can be reasonably assured it is valid, at least as far as can be computationally verified.

Comment: How can i get Authority Information Access from the certificate? can you share me with the code? i need the url from that filed.!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking at this point. I suggest you study the Java documentation for the Certificate classes and do a bit of research on your own. Then, if you still have a question, post a new question here on Stack Overflow.